# Saving 2D array into Laravel session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to convert a pure PHP code to Laravel. This code works with session extensively - here is the simplified part of the code (please ignore syntax errors):

```
    $_SESSION['gamedata']=[
        'game'=> 23 ,
        'n'=>0,
        'Cards'=>[],
        'Values'=>[],
    ];
    $_SESSION['gamedata']['Cards'][]= getCard();
    $_SESSION['gamedata']['Values'][]= getVal();
```

right now based on the laravel documentation my option is

```
    session(['gamedata' =>  [
        'game'=> 23 ,
        'n'=>0,
        'Cards'=>[],
        'Values'=>[],
    ]]);

    $gamedata = session('gamedata');
    $gamedata['Cards'][]= getCard();
    session(['gamedata'=>$gamedata]);

    $gamedata = session('gamedata');
    $gamedata['Values'][]= getVal();
    session(['gamedata'=>$gamedata]);
```

which is very stupid ... and no i cant save it one at the end of the line becuz functions also work with session so session needs to be saved before each function call

basically i want to be able to save in 2d session instantly something like

```
session([ ['gamedata']['Cards'][] => getCards() ]);
```

which right now gives me this error

```
Cannot use [] for reading
```

even this code

```
session([ ['gamedata']['Cards'] => getCards() ]);
```

gives me this error

```
Undefined index: Cards
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, `session([key => value])` is a shortcut for `\Session::put(key, value)`. You can use dots as path separators in the key if you want to update a nested session value.

If you want to replace a value in the session, each of the following lines will do so:

```
session([ 'gamedata.Cards' => getCards() ]);
\Session::put('gamedata.Cards', getCards());
```

If, however, the value in the session is an array you want to add to, the following line will do the trick:

```
\Session::push('gamedata.Cards', getCards());
```

Unfortunately, there is no shortcut version for this syntax using the `session()` helper.

Comment: thanx , but `gamedata.Cards` itself is an array and i want to add values to that array not replace its value with new value or am i mistaken  ? basically i want `cards[] = newval` not `cards=newval`